# Searching for a tail tool for Linux to colorize and suppress lines by regx?

Tags: regex, tail

Is there any tool that does both, colorize and filtering lines to suppress form output by regex?

Comment: Cleaned out the comments-posted-as-answers. You'll have to resolve your browser isssue.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to use a combination of `tail`, `grep` and `ccze`.

For example,

`tail -f /var/log/messages | grep foo | ccze`

Comment: Yes, with ccze this beats multitail for me.

Answer (score 2):

multitail does exactly what you're asking for and a whole lot more inside an ncurses interface.

---

multitail (at least on Ubuntu 10.04) ships with a well populated sample config file that will provide nice coloring on most system logs out of the box.  A simpler quick-start version of a multitailrc would look like this:

```
defaultcscheme:foo

colorscheme:foo:all my foo messages
cs_re_s:red,white,bold/blink:([^:]*): says foo!
cs_re:green:.*: says foo!
cs_re:cyan:.*: says bar

# filter out the baz lines with this filterscheme
filterscheme:foo:gets rid of the baz
rule:ev:.*: says baz

usefilterscheme:foo:/var/log/foo
```

Both `cs_re` and `cs_re_s` have a similar format:

```
cs_re:FG_COLOR[,BG_COLOR[,ATTRIBUTE[/ANOTHER_ATTRIBUTE]]]:REGEX
```

`cs_re_s` will colorize only the substrings (things in parentheses).

This should get you started with multitail.  If you want to get more fancy, take a look through the sample one provided with it and/or the docs.

Comment: multitail does a lot. That being said, I still have affinity for how tail -f *.log displays multiple files. And multitail UI is not the easiest to get used to, but that's related to the fact it does a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe tail to grep to suppress line output with regex.

`tail input.txt | grep -v -e regex_pattern`

Grep can alternatively colorize the parts that match the regex, makes finding a pattern in a log file easier.

Colorizing it by regex might be interesting though.

Answer (score 0):

Lots - is google down again? mtail, colortail, multitail...

Comment: What search string to you type into google to get those answers? What are the advantages / disadvantages of each? This is a completely valid question for this site.